# Does "between A and B" include the endpoints? (Eg, "What is the probability [of] between $2$ and $6$ [manufacturing] imperfections ...?")

Tags: terminology, poisson-distribution, interval-arithmetic

> A manufacturing process produces circuit boards that sometime have imperfections. The average number of imperfections are $0.67$ per circuit board. Suppose a batch containing $5$ circuit boards is sent to a quality control team for inspection. What is the probability that the team finds between $2$ and $6$ imperfections **in total**?

I'm not too sure whether this should be interpreted as $P(X)$ over $(2,6)$ or $[2,6]$.

Comment: In this context, you would be using $[2,6]$, but this is a narrow grammatical cause.  Note that the discrete context would give you $[3,5]$ as the other option.

Comment: I agree with @abiessu: definitely $[2,6]$.

Comment: Also, minor note on my formatting edits: the use of `>` to highlight a question is a general preference, while the use of `$` or sometimes `$$` surrounding mathematical expressions is a more highly desired formatting choice.

Comment: If the distribution is continuous, the interpretation is irrelevant as $\{2\}$ and $\{6\}$ have null measure.